# primefaces for glassfish server 6 and (jakarta9)

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, glassfish

Does primefaces work with jakarta ee? I'm trying to use it with GlassFish-6.5. When i add the library primefaces-12.0.0-jakarta-sources.jar and run my web app i get

```
Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.webapp.UploadedFileCleanerListener
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:98)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:480)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:512)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:361)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:542)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:361)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:533)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1441)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1823)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1699)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:510)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:440)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:34)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
|#]
  Exception while loading the app|#]
  Undeployment failed for context /WebApplication1|#]
  Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.webapp.UploadedFileCleanerListener|#]
```

i tried to use another lib primefaces-11.0.0-RC2-jakarta-sources.jar. But the problem remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the sources JAR just use the regular JAR.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>12.0.0</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
```